# What's wrong with my logic statement here?

Tags: logic

tl;dr: pls fix my spaghetti code

Hi all. I'm a physics undergrad and I work in a lab at my university doing gamma spec. Mostly for fun/learning to program, I'm trying to write a module that reads the ASCII spectra format that my software exports. I've managed to write something that parses the file for the relevant bin numbers/counts, locates and applies the calibration factors, and generates a plot. It works fine (though I'm open to suggestions to make it better), but I've found that accidentally evaluating the cell twice causes a bunch of errors. There's an easy work around (just don't evaluate it again), but I took it as a challenge. My idea was to just use a logic statement, but it seems like its getting ignored completely whenever I hit shift-enter. Here is what I've tried to do (most of the stuff towards the bottom isn't super important; I think whatever's going wrong is at the top):

```
ReadSpe[FileName_, EnergyIn_] := 
 If[ValueQ[EnergyIn], 
  Print["Please clear the expression " <> ToString[EnergyIn] <> 
" before preceeding with ReadSpe"], doIfFalse[FileName, EnergyIn]]

 (*The idea here is that I want it to abort if the provided expression is 
 already defined*)

doIfFalse[FileName_, EnergyIn_] := (
  Clear[CalIn, DataIn, InFile, Np];
  InFile = OpenRead[FileName];
  CalIn = {};
  DataIn = {};
  EnergyIn = {};
  (*Creates data set "CallIn","DataIn",
   "EnergyIn"and initializes them empty*)
  Do[Read[InFile, String], {i, 1, 11}];
  (*Skips past preamble to the data in.Spe file*)
  Np = Part[Read[InFile, {Number, Number}], 2] + 1;
  (*Picks out the list length that is in the next data line and saves \
   it to "Np"*)
  Do[AppendTo[DataIn, {i - 1, Read[InFile, Number]}], {i, 1, Np}];
  (*Creates a data set with the form {{bin,count},{bin,count},...}*)
  Do[Read[InFile, String], {i, 1, 10}];
  (*Now reads SPE file to find calibration constants*)
  AppendTo[CalIn, Read[InFile, {Number, Number, Number}]];
 Do[AppendTo[
    EnergyIn, {CalIn[[1, 1]] + CalIn[[1, 2]]*DataIn[[i, 1]] + 
    CalIn[[1, 3]]*(DataIn[[i, 1]])^2, DataIn[[i, 2]]}], {i, 1, Np}];
  (*Creates a list of pairs of the form (energy,counts*)
  Close[InFile];
  Clear[CalIn, DataIn, InFile, Np];
  ListPlot[EnergyIn, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Full, 
   AxesLabel -> {HoldForm[Energy[keV]], HoldForm[Counts]}, 
   PlotLabel -> HoldForm[EnergyIn], 
   LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Al Bayan", 12, GrayLevel[0]}, 
   PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 2}](*Plots data*))
```

It works fine on the first pass - it generates the plot, and the data is properly appended to EnergyIn_. Running the module again generates the following error:

```
Set::shape: Lists {{1.4514,0},{1.84485,0},{2.23831,0},{2.63176,0},
{3.02521,0},{3.41866,0},{3.81211,0},{4.20556,0},{4.59901,0},{4.99246,0},
<<32>>,{17.9765,274},{18.3699,185},{18.7634,81},{19.1569,61},{19.5503,58},
{19.9438,52},{20.3372,52},{20.7307,90},<<8142>>} and {} are not the same 
shape.

AppendTo::rvalue: {{1.4514,0},{1.84485,0},{2.23831,0},{2.63176,0},
{3.02521,0},{3.41866,0},{3.81211,0},{4.20556,0},{4.59901,0},{4.99246,0},
<<32>>,{17.9765,274},{18.3699,185},{18.7634,81},{19.1569,61},{19.5503,58},
{19.9438,52},{20.3372,52},{20.7307,90},<<8142>>} is not a variable with a 
value, so its value cannot be changed.

AppendTo::rvalue: {{1.4514,0},{1.84485,0},{2.23831,0},{2.63176,0},
{3.02521,0},{3.41866,0},{3.81211,0},{4.20556,0},{4.59901,0},{4.99246,0},
<<32>>,{17.9765,274},{18.3699,185},{18.7634,81},{19.1569,61},{19.5503,58},
{19.9438,52},{20.3372,52},{20.7307,90},<<8142>>} is not a variable with a 
value, so its value cannot be changed.

AppendTo::rvalue: {{1.4514,0},{1.84485,0},{2.23831,0},{2.63176,0},
{3.02521,0},{3.41866,0},{3.81211,0},{4.20556,0},{4.59901,0},{4.99246,0},
<<32>>,{17.9765,274},{18.3699,185},{18.7634,81},{19.1569,61},{19.5503,58},
{19.9438,52},{20.3372,52},{20.7307,90},<<8142>>} is not a variable with a 
value, so its value cannot be changed.

General::stop: Further output of AppendTo::rvalue will be suppressed during 
this calculation.
```

Then it just outputs the list as an 8142x2 matrix. Pls help me I know not what I am doing.

Comment: TL;DR if you know where stuff is going wrong, why do you simply dump all your "spaghetti code" here and believe this is appealing? Why not at least try to make this a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is most likely `If[ValueQ[x], ...]`. Check this out:

```
test[x_] := ValueQ[x]

Clear[var];
test[var]

(* Out: False *)

var = {1,2,3};
test[var]

(* Out: False *)
```

`var` evaluates before it is passed to the function `test`, so `test[var]` is equivalent to `test[{1,2,3}]`. `ValueQ[{1, 2, 3}]` is `False`.

This is different from

```
var = {1, 2, 3};
ValueQ[var]
```

because in this case `var` is not evaluated before it is passed to the function, in this case `ValueQ`. The reason for this is that `ValueQ` has the `HoldAll` attribute:

```
Attributes[ValueQ]
(* Out: {HoldAll, Protected, ReadProtected} *)
```

What `ValueQ` answers is the question: "If this expression is evaluated, will its value change?" If you pass a variable such as `var` to `ValueQ` then the answer is yes, because `var` will evaluate to `{1, 2, 3}`. But if you pass `{1, 2, 3}` to `ValueQ` then the answer is no, because `{1, 2, 3}` evaluates to `{1, 2, 3}`.

Try `SetAttributes[Readspe, HoldRest]`. If it does not solve the problem, try rewriting your code in a way that does not require you to assign a value to a variable that you pass into the function. That kind of programming can become quite advanced in *Mathematica*, it requires a good knowledge of how evaluation works.

The code reminds me of how things are often done in C, where you send a pointer to a function and it modifies the value that the pointer points to. That strategy is not very good in *Mathematica*, and you will find that you will like the language more if you avoid it.

I would recommend using `Module` instead of clearing variables at every function call.